# How to push_back a "unique_ptr<Base>&" to "vector<unique_ptr<Derived>>"

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I need to move elements between 2 `vector<unique_ptr>` with some condition checkings. After moving, I will ignore the from-vector (transfer the ownership to the to-vector).

**Case 1**: Move from `vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> fromDeriveds` to `vector<unique_ptr<Base>> toBases`:

```cpp
vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> fromDeriveds;
vector<unique_ptr<Base>> toBases;
   
for (unique_ptr<Derived> &derived: fromDeriveds)
{
    if (derived->prop == 1)
    {
        toBases.push_back(move(derived));
    }
}
```

This case is good.

**Case 2**: Move from `vector<unique_ptr<Base>> fromBases` to `vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> toDeriveds`:

```cpp
vector<unique_ptr<Base>> fromBases;
vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> toDeriveds;
   
for (unique_ptr<Base> &base: fromBases)
{
    Derived *derived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base.get());
    if (derived && derived->prop == 1)
    {
        toDeriveds.push_back(move(base));
    }
}
```

It fails to compile with the following error:

```
main.cpp:44:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Derived> >::push_back(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<Base>&>::type)’
             toDeriveds.push_back(move(base));
                                            ^
```

Although I can do it by the following way, it is a copy instead of a move:

```cpp
vector<unique_ptr<Base>> fromBases;
vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> toDeriveds;
   
for (unique_ptr<Base> &base: fromBases)
{
    Derived *derived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base.get());
    if (derived && derived->prop == 1)
    {
        toDeriveds.push_back(make_unique<Derived>(*derived));
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Related to [alternatives-of-static-pointer-cast-for-unique-ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120424/alternatives-of-static-pointer-cast-for-unique-ptr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on `fromBase` list and make your checks, if that requirement is met then you can simply `release` the pointer - which gives away the base pointer without calling destructor on it. Just make sure to remove such empty pointers that were released, in case you need to use `fromBase` vector again.

[**WANDBOX LINK**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2eZ0kxSR0b96VzfI)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Base{ public: virtual ~Base() = default; };
class Derived: public Base {};


int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>> fromBase;
    vector<unique_ptr<Derived>> toDerived;
    
    fromBase.emplace_back(make_unique<Base>());
    fromBase.emplace_back(make_unique<Base>());
    fromBase.emplace_back(make_unique<Derived>());
    
    for(auto& p: fromBase) {
        Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(p.get());
        // make other checks here
        if(d != nullptr) {
            toDerived.emplace_back(d);
            p.release();
        }
    }

    // make sure to remove released pointers
    fromBase.erase(remove_if(fromBase.begin(), fromBase.end(), [](const auto& p) { return !p; }), fromBase.end());
    
    cout << fromBase.size() << " " << toDerived.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Slightly more concise is just use `remove(fromBase.begin(), fromBase.end(), nullptr)` inside the erase call.

Comment: In C++20, you can use `std::erase(fromBase, nullptr);`

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestion. As I do not care about the fromBase after picking up the record and emplacing to toDerived (so can just leave the fromBase out of scope). I change it to "Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(p.release());", which also releases the ownership before having a new unique_ptr (https://wandbox.org/permlink/s0yfBPweNQKv3Fz5). But one point I am not quite is that you call "toDerived.emplace_back(d)" before "p.release();". Will this result in unexpected behavior as there are 2 unique_ptr to the same object? (https://wandbox.org/permlink/BaHW7dBhScUIkqYM)

Comment: @kzfid no that shouldn't be undefined behavior, however, I'd still suggest keeping the code a bit cleaner as there's no harm in it. Also if you think my answer helped, you can mark it as well :)

Comment: It absolutely helps. ^_^